# How to mark a file for future commiting in TFS?

Tags: c#, tfs

For example I am working on some file. 
I want to mark it like a file for the future commit and i want to do it right now because I will have many files and I can't remember all changes in them. 
And right now I have no access to TFS (I need to connect to VPN to get access to TFS). 
Is there any way to mark a file?

Comment: TFS has a so called offline mode. Perhaps this will help you checking in  files locally and  sync with TFS later?

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy, oh, thanks.i will try

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy, unfortunately this doesn't work

Comment: You need to clearly state whether you're using Git or TFVC, as TFS supports both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TFVC does not support offline work in the same sense as a true distributed version control system like Git.

With local workspaces, you can modify files without checking them out first. They will appear as pending changes, but you won't be able to check the changes in until you have connectivity to the TFVC repository.